# Systemd target based startup sequence

Tags: systemd

I am trying to optimize the systemd based startup sequence of the applications that are run at startup. I have below question on the same

Does Target based dependency actually work for sequencing/ordering of process starts ?
ex : Take the below configuration

```
target t1
{
Wants a.service, b.service, c.service
After a.service, b.service, c.service
}

target t2
{
Wants t1.target, x.service, y.service,z.service
After t1.target, x.service, y.service, z.service
}
```

Here i have added dependency of t1.target on t2 target. So ideally I would expect services wanted in t2.target to be started after all services in t1.target are launched/spawned.
But as I have seen mostly if there is no dependency in the service file(of t2 target) specifically on other service (from t1 target), all services are attempted to start parallely irrespective of target dependency.

1. Is this expectation correct to have target based dependency as above?
2. Even if target dependency exists, is it mandatory to add the service dependency exclusively ?

Any help here is much appreciated.
Thanks in advance :)